Is there a way to use non-inline plugins with Chart.js using the ConsoleTVs/Charts package?
I am working with a Laravel application that uses Backpack and renders charts using the ConsoleTVs/Charts package. From what I've found online, there is no way to use non-inline plugins that require registering; only inline ones can be used using $this->chart->plugins(...).
I want to use the chartjs-plugin-annotation line annotation but this plugin requires registering.
Here is my chart controller I want to add line annotations:
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Charts;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\ChartController;
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Chartjs\Chart;

class ExampleChartController extends ChartController
{
    public function setup(): void
    {
        $this->chart = new Chart();
        $this->chart->labels(['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3']);
        $this->chart->load(backpack_url('charts/example'));
    }

    public function data(): void
    {
        $this->chart->dataset('Group 1', 'bar', [1, 2, 3]);
    }
}

